# Angular E2E Protractor testing : error to join API from testing session

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

For an ***Angular*** application, I'm creating **E2E Tests** from ***Protractor*** and ***Jasmine***.

All feel good except the externals API calls. For example, if I try to test and simulate login, the form will correctly be complete but when I submit it thanks to a click, the API Call is in error with some *CORS errors*.

The CORS errors is not here when I run it outside testing session. All my tests are run in local computer and with a firefox browser.
However, I don't understand why I couldn't join my API's (DRF API on a local docker container). I confirm that the API allows all CORS origins and contains correct headers.

Do you have any idea to fix this problem and to test all the submit login form ?

For my test :

```js
  login(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.navigateToLogin();
    browser.wait(this.getInputUsername().sendKeys(username), 1000);
    browser.wait(this.getInputPassword().sendKeys(password));
    // Wait to show what happens for the demo.
    browser.sleep(500);
    const signInButton = this.getLoginSubmitButton();
    browser.wait(
      signInButton.isDisplayed(),
      1000,
      'sign in button not visible'
    );
    signInButton.click();
    browser.sleep(50000);
  }
```

Comment: CORS errors can not be a thing if the headers in the response are correct. In your place I would check the url of the request being sent. Also you are using browser.wait in a wrong way and this can produce flaky tests.